# Selenium - wait for report generation

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Part of what I am trying to automate are:

1. Go to : [this](https://www.renewablesandchp.ofgem.gov.uk/Public/ReportViewer.aspx?ReportPath=/Renewables/Accreditation/AccreditedStationsExternalPublic&ReportVisibility=1&ReportCategory=1)
2. Pick "25" from the *Page Size* dropdown list (a required selection for generating the report).
3. Click the *View Report* button.
4. Wait for the report to be produced.
5. Click the *Save/Export* button and select the *CSV* option.

[image]

However, how can I set a condition that can detect whether the report is generated? There are 2 possible transitions from step 4 to step 5 - *Loading* or just *Blank* (which I have no idea why):

[image]
[image]

Here is the test case that failed:

[image]

This is my first time using `Selenium`, and I am planning to export this to work with `C#`.

Thank you!

Comment: if you execute script `return document.readyState;` on webdriver does it return `complete` before loading is done?

Comment: What's the relation between Selenium IDE extension for firefox and C#?